# Click button with predicate + XCUITest

Tags: ios, testing, xcode-ui-testing

I am trying to click a button , which is having only Title and it will be changing according to number of products added to the cart.

Here is the properties

[image]

I used the following code to do this

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title BEGINSWITH[cd] 'Cart'")
    let button = XCUIApplication().buttons.element(matching: predicate)
    tap(on: button)
```

But it says element not found.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

And it would be great if you suggest any books for XCUITest.

Comment: What does tap(on:) do?

Comment: it is just a wrapper function for tap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign an accessibility identifier to the label and then you won't need to predicate on the text.

```
// app code
let label: UILabel!
label.accessibilityIdentifier = "cartCount"
```

Then you can search for the label element using the accessibility identifier and access its `label` property if you need to check the count.

```
// test code
let app = XCUIApplication()
let cartLabel = app.staticTexts["cartCoint"]
let cartCountText = cartLabel.label // => "Cart: 5"
```